# How to Better Drag a UIButton? UIButton UIControlEventTouchUpInside Event Is Not Called

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview, uitouch

My draggable button is using these events to be dragged:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(beganDragging:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragOutside | UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(exitDragging:)
                     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

It's straight forward above. Method `wasDragged` adjusts the center of the UIButton to the UITouch location. However, there are cases when I end up with button being hung (normally it snaps to grid after finger release) because `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` is never called!

How? Let's say I start dragging a button and while holding it I make a screenshot (Power+Home). When I release the button no events are ever called (i.e. `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`). Therefore, my button is stuck and not snapping to grid which is in method `exitDragging`

Any light how to make sure `exitDragging` always runs?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is easier using the UIView APIs with `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded` etc.

It seems you are anyway not using the UIButton functionalities. I think that managing a drag with the target mechanism of UIButton is not what it was intended for.